# Backbone events firing multiple times even though I am following proper standards

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events

I have a table that when I click on a row, in a side div I display the details. I have created an event on the row (tr) that is fired every time that row is clicked. The problem I have is that the event is being fired multiple times. It is acting as if a new view is being created everytime the event is fired, but a new view is not being created. Here is the code:

```
GroupView = class App.GroupView extends Backbone.View
    template: App.Utils.getTemplate 'group'
    selectedId: 0

    events:
        'click tr': 'selectGroup'

    selectGroup: (e) ->
        thisEl = $(e.currentTarget)
        $(thisEl).closest('tr').siblings().removeClass 'selected'
        $(thisEl).closest('tr').addClass 'selected'
        @selectedId = $(thisEl).data().id
        @getGroupDetails @selectedId

    render: -> 
        $(@$el).html @template
            groups: @collection.models

        if @selectedId is 0
            firstRowEl = $(@$el).find('tr:first')
            $(firstRowEl).addClass 'selected'
            @selectedId = $(firstRowEl).data().id

        @getGroupDetails @selectedId

    getGroupDetails: (id, platform) ->
        $('<img/>', 
            src: 'img/ajax_loader_2.gif'
            class: 'ajax-loader'
            ).appendTo '.group-details'

        renderGroupDetails id

groupDetails = new GroupDetailsView
    el: '.group-details'
    model: groupDetailsModel

renderGroupDetails = (id)->
    groupDetails.el = '.group-details'
    groupDetails.stopListening groupDetailsModel
    groupDetails.listenTo groupDetailsModel, 'change', ->
    groupDetails.model = 
        groupDetails: groupDetailsModel.toJSON()
    groupDetails.render()

    groupDetailsModel.fetch
        data:
            id: id
        processData: true
```

The issue is that when I use the `groupDetails.stopListening groupDetailsModel`, the multiple event firing issue is resolved but then NONE of the events in the `groupDetails` view is being fired.

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers,

Kianosh

Comment: You're saying that `selectGroup` is getting called several times for each click? Several times with the same `<tr>` target?

Comment: No the call to groupDetails.render() is being called repeatedly.

Comment: Is the indentation in your pasted code messed up or is that your real indentation?

Comment: @mu is too short, I tried to preserve the indentation as best as I could.

Answer (score 3):

So, giving you a specific answer is difficult:  the code you've pasted is a bit hard to follow, and seems like it might be missing bits (eg. what's a `groupDetailsModel`?  Does it have any logic that affects it's view?).  That's ok though, because I think what you need here is more debugging help than a specific answer.

If I understand you correctly, your problem is that `groupDetails.render()` is being invoked extra times, and you're not sure why or what is invoking it: is that correct?  If so, your trusty debugger can answer this in a matter of seconds.

NOTE: Everything I'm about to say applies to Chrome (with the built-in developer tools up) or Firefox (with the Firebug extension up) for sure.  It probably applies to other browsers with their tools too, I just can't say for sure since I don't use them.

**Approach #1: Debugger**

With your debugger up, add a `debugger;` line as the first thing inside your `GroupDetails.prototype.render` method.  This will make your browser pause on that line whenever it hits it.  While its paused you can check the "call stack" on the right-hand side, and that will show you *exactly* what bit of your code just called that render.  You can also use the debugger to inspect the values of the different variables in your environment to try and understand *why* your code is calling `render`.

**Approach #2: Console.trace**

If you're not a fan of using the debugger, there's another tool that's also perfect for answering this sort of question.  Simply add `console.trace()` as the first line in your render method, then run your code as normal.  This time your browser will log (to the "console") a stack trace generated from that point in the code.  This stack trace is similar to the call stack that you can see when you use `debugger`, and thus it will tell you exactly what code invoked the `render` each time.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey, how come I didn't know about console.trace? Awesome, thanks!

Comment: I tried this and still not able to understand why it is still delegating these events. I ended up doing a couple of things:
- Undelegating the 'change' event on the model
- Undelegating all the events in the container div

I don't think this is the correct approach and think it should be handled better. But I do not know if it is b/c of my understanding of Backbone (or lack there of) or a Backbone issue in general.

Comment: Well so first you want to try adding either a `console.trace()` or `debugger` as I suggested, then you want to check the call stack.  There should be a line in it that's a `trigger` method, and the line before that should be the source of your multiple event calls.